# Find the tangent plane for $\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ at $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Find a function whose graph is the tangent plane to the graph at the indicated point. Sketch the graph of the function and the tangent plane near th epoint of tangency.

Tangent plane formula: $$z = f(a,b)+(x-a)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b) + (y-b)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,b)$$

Use the formula for the following equation: $\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ at $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$

Given that three points are required then:

$\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}=z=1-x^2-y^2-z^2=0=x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ - which is a ball with radius 1

Then evaluating the partial derivative in respect to $(x,y,z)$, I get:

$\frac{\partial f}{x}=2x;\frac{\partial f}{y}=2y;\frac{\partial f}{z}=2z$

Calculating $f(a,b)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1+2\sqrt{2}}{4}$

Putting the points into the differentiated variables we get:
$$\frac{\partial f}{x}=1;\frac{\partial f}{y}=1;\frac{\partial f}{z}=1$$

And finally placing everything into the equation:

$\frac{1+2\sqrt{2}}{4}+(x-\frac{1}{2})+(y-\frac{1}{2})+(z-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$

I am unsure whether I have approached this correctly given the extra variable $z$ which is new to me.

Using an online graphing calculator I get:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the formula you quoted incorrectly. $f(x,y)$ should be a function from the equation of the surface of the form
$$
z= f(x,y).
$$
We have the equation $z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$, thus, $f(x,y)=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$. Further,
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= \frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}},\quad
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}= \frac{-2y}{2\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}};
$$
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)= \frac{-1/2}{\sqrt{1/2}}=-\frac1{\sqrt2},\quad
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)= \frac{-1/2}{\sqrt{1/2}}=-\frac1{\sqrt2}.
$$
Finally, according to the formula, the equation of
the tangent plane is
$$
z=\frac1{\sqrt2}+\left(x-\frac12\right)\cdot\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)+\left(y-\frac12\right)\cdot\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right).
$$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I got a little carried away when the third point was introduced

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of notation flaws that should be pointed out.  First you mean "$f(x,y)= \sqrt{1- x^2- y^2}$" not just "$\sqrt{1- x^2- y^2}$".  Second, while you can write $z= \sqrt{1- x^2- y^2}$ that is NOT **equal** to $1- x^2- y^2- z^2$ which is NOT **equal** to $x^2+ y^2+ z^2= 1$.  Third, the graph is not a sphere.  It is a hemisphere, that part of the sphere $x^2+ y^2+ z^2= 1$ that is above the xy-plane. Fourth, $\frac{1+ 2\sqrt{2}}{4}+ (x-\frac{1}{2})+ (y- \frac{1}{2})+ (z- \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ is NOT an equation at all, there is no "=". Finally, the picture from your on-line graphing calculator clearly shows the plane cutting through the sphere not tangent to it!

You are given $z= \sqrt{1- x^2- y^2}$.  That **can** be written as $z^2= 1- x^2+ y^2$ or $x^2+ y^2+ z^2= 1$ as long as you keep in mind that z is non-negative.   Yes that is a hemisphere and a tangent plane to a sphere is orthogonal to the radius at that point.  The center of the hemisphere is (0, 0, 0) and $\frac{1}{2}\vec{i}+ \frac{1}{2}\vec{j}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\vec{k}$ is the radial vector at $\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$.   The tangent plane at that point is $\frac{1}{2}\left(x- \frac{1}{2}\right)+ \frac{1}{2}\left(y- \frac{1}{2}\right)+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(z- \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)= 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You obtained the point of tangency correctly. It is $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{\sqrt2})$ on the hemisphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1, z \geq 0$.

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2x = 1;\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2y = 1;\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=2z = \sqrt2 \ $. *Note You made a mistake in calculation of $\frac {\partial f}{\partial z}$. Rest are fine.*

So equation of plane is,

$(x-\frac{1}{2}) + (y - \frac{1}{2}) + \sqrt2 (z - \frac{1}{\sqrt2}) = 0$

$x + y + \sqrt2 z = 2$